# IOS Safari, in javascript get absolute position from screen of mouseclick, excluding scroll-area

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say i have in iOS a big vertical space of pictures, so the user can scroll.

The vertical space is 2000 long.

I would like to get the mouse position the user clicks via document.

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
           console.log( event);
            // event.screenY gives the Y including the scrolled area.
        }, true);
```

So if the iphone has a height of 700 , I want to get the screenY, if i scroll to the bottom and click, equal little less than 700 and not less than 2000.

On android it works correctly. on iOS not so.

go to wikipedia and test on debugger/browserstack via pasting my code there in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

There are five different x and y positions on a webpage:

- screenX and screenY
- pageX and pageY
- clientX and clientY
- layerX and layerY
- offsetX and offsetY

If screenY is not working try some of the others out and find the one that works.